# prevent copy past-clear Field upon change list

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA code in excel for

1- prevent the copy past cut in a certain ranges of column in excel
as these cells will choose the fields inside it through validation list

2-upon make changes in certain column , other column with be cleared

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a answer you need to tell us what you've already tried, a code or something so we can tell why it isn't working and how to correct